# What statistical test can I use to compare proportions across two different groups containing multiple populations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion, biostatistics

I am trying to answer a research question about whether the presence of a certain pathogen affects the age structure of frog populations.

**Study set up**:
Samples were taken from frogs at multiple study sites and tested for the presence of the pathogen. If at least one frog at a given study site had the pathogen, then that site was said to have pathogen presence. So all sites are split into two groups -- pathogen is present and pathogen is not present. Additionally, each frog that was sampled was identified as either tadpole, juvenile, or adult.

I want to compare the proportions of tadpoles, juveniles, and adults between the two groups to see if the presence of the pathogen at a site has a statistically significant effect on the age structure. I considered doing a chi-squared test since I am trying to compare proportions across groups, but I'm not sure if that would exactly work in this situation since the groups are not made up of individual frogs, but are instead made up of the many different sites that frog samples were taken from.

**Additional Info**: There are 76 total sites. Frogs sampled no more than 500m apart were considered to be from the same site. The number of frogs sampled at each site varies from 1 to around 60 frogs. The sites were spread over a relatively variable landscape (differences in vegetation, water presence, elevation, etc.). In regard to these possible differences, I only have actual data on the different elevations at each site.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) You say treatment groups, but you don't seem to have actively applied any treatment, so thee is observational data. 2) How many sites? Could there be other differences between sites? About how many frogs at each site? Does this number vary much? Differences between sites could maybe show up as *overdispersion*

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for bringing up these points! I've edited the question to include this information.